# Pycharm 2020.1 doesn't find minidom in python 3.6 in Linux Mint

Tags: python, pycharm, linux-mint, minidom

I was trying to test some **xml.dom.minidom** APIs and I use pycharm 2020.1 for Linux Mint, python 3.6

Some article says the lib is part of python standard library, however when I tried to "import xml.dom.minidom" pycharm seemed trying to install the package while I was typing the "import" statement, it failed to do so with this error message:

```
command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-lzfw_pe7/dom/
```

pycharm then suggested use command line to do the same same thing, further investigation showed that a prerequisite is needed:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

after that it seemed "pip install dom" proceed w/o error, and from pycharm's configuration view I could find it:

[image]

Still I couldn't import the package, as shown below:

[image]

I further looked into the python lib directory:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/dom-0.9-py3.6.egg-info/
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff   1 May 10 17:32 dependency_links.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 221 May 10 17:32 installed-files.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 895 May 10 17:32 PKG-INFO
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff  30 May 10 17:32 requires.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 192 May 10 17:32 SOURCES.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff   8 May 10 17:32 top_level.txt
```

The timestamp indicated this is newly installed package but we noticed that .py file is missing, indicating a failed installation.

My question:

1. is this xml.dom.minidom part of standard library? is additional step required to use this lib?
2. Is this a bug from pycharm 2020.1? Why did it fail to install a package or how I can install it either from within pycharm or a terminal window?

I believe if I install anaconda this package might be included but that's not what I wanted anyway.

Comment: Which version of Linux Mint? How did you install this Python instance?

Comment: Thanks for responding. It's Mint 19.3 - I don't recall how python was installed, most likely though its package manager apt.